# CSV Wildcard within string

Tags: python, csv, wildcard

I am using a CSV file to read in terms that I am looking for in a text file.

I would like to use a wildcard or 'Like' as a term. I am not looking for wildcard for text document name but for the terms I'm searching for found in the CSV file.

For example:
Terms in CSV file to search in Text File, each term is in it's own row.

test* #search for test, tests, testing, etc
project
list
table
chair

Is there a wildcard that can be used in the CSV file so that all variants of that word is returned?
I want to place the wildcard in the CSV file.

Below is my code, the file it reads the terms I'm searching for is contract_search_terms.csv

```
def main():
    txt_filepaths = glob.glob("**/*.txt", recursive=True)
    start = time.time()
    results = {}
    new_results = [] #place dictionary values organized per key = value instead of key = tuple of values 
    term_filename = open('contract_search_terms.csv', 'r') #file where terms to be searched is found
    term_file = csv.DictReader(term_filename)
    search_terms =[] #append terms into a list, this means that we can use several columns and append them all to one list.
    
    #############search for the terms imported into the list############################################################
    for col in term_file:
                
        search_terms.append(col['Contract Terms']) #indicate what columns you want read in

    print(search_terms) #this is just a check to show what terms are in the list
    
    for filepath in txt_filepaths:
        print(f"Searching document {filepath}")   #print what file the code is reading
        
        search_terms = search_terms #place terms list into search_terms so that the code below can read it when looping through the contracts.
                    
        filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
        found_terms = {} #dictionary of the terms found
        
        line_number={}
        
        
        for term in search_terms:
            if term in found_terms.keys():
                continue
                
            with open(filepath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as fp:
                lines = str(fp.readlines()).split('.') #turns contract file lines as a list
                
                for line in lines:
                    if line.find(term) != -1: #line by line is '-1', paragraph '\n'
                        line_number = lines.index(line)
                        new_results.append(f"'{term}' New_Column '{filename}' New_Column '{line}' New_Column '{line_number}'") #placing the results from the print statement below into a list
                        print(f"Found '{term}' in document '{filename}' in line '{line_number}'") 

                    if term in results.keys():
                        pages = results[''.join(term)].append([filename,line,line_number])

                    else:
                        results[term] = [filename]

                #Place results into dataframe and create a csv file to use as a check if results_reports is not correct
                d2=pd.DataFrame(new_results, columns=['Results']) #passing the list to a dataframe and giving it a column title
                d2.to_csv('results.csv', index=True)
```

Comment: You can use whatever notation you like, but it's going to be up to you to interpret that notation and do the more sophisticated search.  `line.find(term)` is not going to do it.  You'll probably end up with something like `re.search`.

Comment: And, by the way, a file with a list of words is not a CSV file.  It's just a text file.

Comment: @TimRoberts the list of words is in a csv file, I didn't attached it because it's just a term per row, so I displayed it as text. If you look at the code it's reading in the csv file to get the terms I'm using to search the text file. Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into it.

Comment: Right.  I'm just saying, there are no commas, so it's not a "comma-separated" file.  It's just a text file.  CSV has a very specific meaning.  People are using the word CSV to describe text files that are nothing like a CSV.

Comment: ok, I say CSV because the file is a a .csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to simplify the code flow without testing the term for a wildcard and then branching to another kind of searching I suggest you generally use the regular expression module (available in standard Python distribution):

```
import re
```

and the regular expression patterns as terms for the regular expression search:

```
lst_found_terms = re.findall(term, line)
if lst_found_terms != []: 
    for found_term in lst_found_terms:
```

instead of:

```
if line.find(term) != -1:
```

If you look exactly for `'test'` the regex pattern will be simply the same as in the find() function ( i.e. `'test'` ) and if you want to find all words beginning with `'test'` the pattern will be `r'\btest\w*'`.

In other words the 'wildcard' for any TERM ending will be enclosing the term with the prefix r'\b' and the ending  r'\w*' (stored in CSV as: `\bTERM\w*`).

Regular expressions provide the possibility to perform case insensitive search if you use the parameter `flags=re.I` in  `re.findall()`.

The simple condition proposed in another answer `if 'test' in line:` will evaluate to True also for 'attestation' or 'contest'. To avoid this the 'wildcard' of the regex sets a word boundary at the beginning of the term ( `r'\b'` ).

Notice that not limiting the number of extension characters for 'test' will find with the wildcard also 'testosterone'. You can limit the number of extending characters replacing `*` with `{0,3}` for maximal 3 additional characters (covering tests and testing but not testosterone).

Comment: thank you so much! this worked for me perfectly. A partial word can be used without any "wildcard" character needed.

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case (`test`, `tests`, `testing`), simple [in operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) might be sufficient, e.g.:

`"test" in line` will evaluate to `True` for all three words and `if "test" in line:` would do the work.

In more complex cases, you might want to use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: the words are coming from a csv file, so I can be searching for hundreds of terms but maybe 10 terms I could be searching for a variants (here is where a type of wildcard is needed).

Comment: You can also use [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html) and there you can use `?` wildcard for one character and `*` for many characters